# Coding Animated GIFS into Email

Tags: html-email, dynamic-programming, animated-gif, email-client

I'm working on a new email marketing campaign for my current employer that involves some small animated GIFs. I know they work on most clients except Outlook 2007 and 2010; so I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically code a separate static image for those clients where the animated GIF does not work.

I know most clients just use the first image of the GIF as a default, but in our case and because of legal reasons, we need to code in a separate, static image.

I'm not an experienced coder but I do know my way around email newsletters and I've done my research on a lot of web design and email coding blogs, but none of them seemed to have the answer. There was one service called Livelicker that seemed to have an answer, but it required subscription and payment, and I don't have the budget for that right now. Here's a link to where they provide some hope: http://www.videoemail.com/faq/#Do_I_have_control_over_the_static_image_that.27s_served_for_Outlook_2007.3F

If anybody has any info for me, I'd be much obliged. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the only way to do it is on server side. You would have to link to a generic image url and rely on the image being dynamically returned. Something like the way [lorempixel.com works](http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/) (refresh this URL to see random images)

Alternatively, if you don't want the start of your GIF animation to be the default fallback image, how about using just a single frame instead. If the GIF does play, the single frame will be hard to notice.